# Adding script to OpenCart

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart

In creating a module I'm trying to avoid overwriting files and I would like to add JS script to OpenCart head section inside the admin area. I do this inside the module I created.

In the controller I added

```
$this->document->addScript('my-script.js'); 
$this->document->addStyle('my-style.css');
```

This works only on the module edit page, not everywhere. How do I do it so it gets added to all pages inside the OpenCart admin area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that code to `admin/controller/common/header.php` inside the `index()` method and it will be added everywhere in the admin panel.

Alternately, you can use vQmod to achieve the same affect without modifying the controller directly:

```
<modification>
    <file name="admin/controller/common/header.php">
    <operation error="log">
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[function index() {]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            $this->document->addScript('my-script.js');
            $this->document->addStyle('my-style.css');      
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Comment: I don't want to override any file...is this really the only way? In that case OC doesn't have it set up right...

Comment: I've updated my answer to illustrate a way to add this with vQmod without modifying core code.

Comment: is there a way without vQmod ?

Comment: I'm creating a module and I'm trying to avoid overriding core file but instead add script when the module installed.

Comment: You could accomplish this with a vQmod that first checks if your extension is installed.  Pretty much follow the same logic as above with an additional check on the extension table.  Either that or a core modification that does the same.  If you want to modify everywhere in the admin panel you'll need to modify the header file either directly or dynamically.

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to update your question since you didn't really make these requirements clear.

Comment: Not sure why you downvoted my answer.  It does exactly what you asked for and I provided additional help in the comments section.  Care to explain?

Comment: isn't there a way to extend ControllerCommonHeader class from admin/controller/common/header.php in a separate file so I don't need to override the file?

Comment: You could add a preaction to index.php which calls your extension controller, performs checks to see if it's installed, etc like this `$controller->addPreAction(new Action('module/my_extension/addscripts'));`

Comment: I'm afraid to add scripts to opencart globally on the admin side you'll need to either overwrite core fies or use vQmod to do so.